# slide from right, after sending form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script for sending messages to support, but in this box, after "send" content disappear, and from right, should slide "Thank you" text. I tried with slide, but nothing happens... I mean, script works (sending message), but thank you doesn't appear. How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="message">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="form">

        </div>
        <div id="thankyou">
            <div id="text">
                Thank you!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#send").click(function(){

$.post("send.php", $("#form").serialize(),  function(response) {

$("#form").hide();
$("#thankyou").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);


});
return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Add html code too please.

Comment: you are using "slide" method which requires `jquery ui` have you included it?

Comment: yes I have included jQuery libs, because I've worked on them :)

Comment: @user3171550 if you could mention your jquery and jquery ui versions too.

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.10.3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need jQuery ui for this too:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

add the appropriate library.

[a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhtm9/)